# Accordion - open a tab on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

The below code opens the first tab on load.

```
var accordion_head = $('.accordion > li > a'),
    accordion_body = $('.accordion li > .sub-menu');

// Open the first tab on load

accordion_head.first().addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');
```

How can I open a tab by name/id or position on the list (e.g. the 4th item)?

Comment: See [`:eq() Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: You should use the `active` option - `$(".accordion").accordion({ active: 3});` ( http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open 4th item like:

```
accordion_head.eq(3).addClass('active').next().slideDown('normal');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initialize the accordion with the active option specified (zero-based index):
$("#myAccordionId").accordion({ active: 3 });

// Set the active option, after initialization (zero-based index):
$("#myAccordionId").accordion( "option", "active", 3 );
```

More about [Accordion Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Answer (score 0):

try this , it  will work

```
$( function() {
  $('#accordion').accordion({
      active : 2
  });
});
```

Thanks